# skimage's rgb2gray in python: AttributeError: Nonetype object has no attribute ndim

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

I was using this code (with skimage version 0.10.0) as far as I can remember without issues:

```
from scipy import misc
import scipy.io as sio
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

img = cv2.imread(myfile)
img = rgb2gray(img)
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work_asaaki\code\generateProposals.py", line 48, in <module>
    img = rgb2gray(img)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 635, in rgb2gray
    if rgb.ndim == 2:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

What could the problem possibly be? How can I fix it to be able to convert the image to grayscale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the error message your problem is that the `imread` call fails, which means `img`is `None`.

Reason for why the `imread` call fails is usually that the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: that was it. the files were all png but I was using .jpg in the *myfile* path.